# PHP script for generating HTML files stopping early

Tags: php, html, csv

I am extremely new to PHP and am having some issues with my first script. I am attempting to use this PHP script to generate HTML files for a series of products that only have minor changes between them. I have a .csv spreadsheet with all of the information, an html template and the PHP script I will post below.

Here is the problem I am encountering. When I check the folder where the script is supposed to put my finished HTML files after running the script, there are only 4 files instead of the 36 I want it to make. There are 36 rows of information in the .csv and I can't figure out how to get the script to generate all of the HTML files it should.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
$base_template = file_get_contents('template.html');
$file_to_read = 'spreadsheet.csv';

ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", 1); 
$filename = '';

if (($handle = fopen($file_to_read, "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $Column1 = $data[0];
    $Column2 = $data[1];
    $Column3 = $data[2];
    $Column4 = $data[3];
    $Column5 = $data[4];
    $Column6 = $data[5];
    $Column7 = $data[6];

    $filename = preg_replace('/[\s\W]+/','',$Column1);
    $filename =  substr($filename, 0, 10);

    $template = str_replace('{Column1}', $Column1, $base_template);
    $template = str_replace('{Column2}', $Column2, $template);
    $template = str_replace('{Column3}', $Column3, $template);
    $template = str_replace('{Column4}', $Column4, $template);
    $template = str_replace('{Column5}', $Column5, $template);
    $template = str_replace('{Column6}', $Column6, $template);
    $template = str_replace('{Column7}', $Column7, $template);

    $file = fopen('generated_html/'.$filename.'.html',"w+");
    fwrite($file, $template);   
    fclose($file);
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

How can I get the script to generate all of the files I need instead of stopping early?

Comment: Step 1: Put a debug output into your loop, so that you see how many iterations it actually goes through.

Comment: can you supply both template.html and spreadsheet.csv?

Comment: Sure that the content of the first column, that you are using as the file name, is unique (after the trimming & cutting)? You might simply be overwriting the same file multiple times.

Comment: Also make sure that you have proper PHP error reporting enabled. And check the return value of fopen - if your file name still contains some "invalid" characters, opening the file for writing might simply fail.

Comment: Your suggestion worked CBroe. The first column was the SKU for each product and they were very similar for the first 10 letters so it must have been overwriting the same files. I took that part of the code out and it worked the first time. Thank you so much for replying and for all your suggestions.